# Subversion svn merge failure

Tags: svn, merge

I started a new `ipv6` branch about a year ago, committing my work on the branch from time to time.  Meanwhile, no changes occurred on the trunk.  Finally, after committing the last change in the branch, I turned to another machine where there was a working copy of trunk, and from there I did:

```bash
svn merge ^/branches/ipv6
```

It showed several, apparently correct additions and updates, mixed with messages such as, for example:

```bash
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r93 through r107 into '.':
 U   .
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r93 through r107 into 'ibd-judge.c':
 U   ibd-judge.c
--- Eliding mergeinfo from 'ibd-judge.c':
 U   ibd-judge.c
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r93 through r107 into 'test/TESTjudge.c':
 U   test/TESTjudge.c
--- Eliding mergeinfo from 'test/TESTjudge.c':
```

I expected both working copies to be the same at that point.  There had been no changes in the trunk copy, so merging of the feature branch should have resulted in applying the changes that I had been carrying out manually during development, shouldn't it?

I realized the unexpected behavior when I went back to the development machine where the working copy was `branches/ipv6` and did:

```bash
svn switch ^/trunk
```

Disaster.  I realized the files I still had in the editor were different from the ones in the working copy.  I overwrote all them, then I checked out `branches/ipv6` in another directory and copied from there some more files that had been modified.

For `svn info`, in the machine where I did the merge I have:

```bash
Relative URL: ^/trunk
Revision: 107
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Rev: 91
Last Changed Date: 2022-04-28 20:27:01 +0200 (Thu, 28 Apr 2022)
```

in the development machine, where I checked out `branches/ipv6`:

```bash
Relative URL: ^/branches/ipv6
Revision: 107
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Rev: 107
Last Changed Date: 2024-03-16 15:18:20 +0100 (Sat, 16 Mar 2024)
```

And in the directory where I did the switch and recovery (not yet committed):

```bash
Relative URL: ^/trunk
Revision: 107
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Rev: 91
Last Changed Date: 2022-04-28 20:27:01 +0200 (Thu, 28 Apr 2022)
```

Both machines have svn, version 1.14.2 (r1899510).

Is that a Subversion bug or am I doing something wrong?

Now I'm going to commit the recovered files to trunk.  What should I've done instead?

Comment: Your approach looks reasonable. Did you perhaps forget to `svn commit` your changes after `svn merge`'ing them? Your trunk still being on r91 (not r108) looks a bit strange.

Comment: Yes, I probably didn't commit after merge.  The merge was bad, however.  After recovering the files and before committing the recovery, files on the merged working copy differed from the recovered ones.